# tor-browser opens with and unexpected error window

Tags: tor-browser

When starting tor-browser I get a error window stating the message below:

> Vidalia detected that the Tor software exited unexpectedly. Please
>   check the message log for recent warning or error messages.

Logfiles showing errors:

```
[Warning] /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor is not owned by this user (MYUSERNAME, 1000) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
[Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor"
[Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Am not allowed to run `tor-browser` as root, i tried purging it, and reinstalling it again, but same error.

I installed tor-browser with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/tor64 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

**Question**: *How do i get tor-browser to work again?*
**Note**: *Am Running Ubuntu 13.04 amd64*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the installation is finished, set the right ownership on the ~/.tor-browser:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.tor-browser
```